# Filtering Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a form hoping to give the user the option filter a report. The form has list boxes to select options, a filter button and a clear button. In the bottom of the form I added the subreport so it can update based on the filter criteria. How can I call out the subreport in the code so it filters? It works if I do it directly on the report with `Report![List]` but it wont update on the form subreport. I'm also not getting all the records showing when filtered because records that have one of the two criteria blank won't appear due to the `If Len(strSubsystem) = 0 Then strSubsystem = "Like '*'"` statement. Is there another statement I can use besides `"like '*'"` to have all records show.

Here's the code

```vb
Private Sub cmdApplyFilter_Click()
     Dim varItem As Variant
     Dim strSubsystem As String
     Dim strStatus As String
     Dim strFilter As String

' Build criteria string from subsystem listbox
    For Each varItem In Me.lstSubsystems.ItemsSelected
         strSubsystem = strSubsystem & ",'" & Me.lstSubsystems.ItemData(varItem) _
         & "'"
     Next varItem
     If Len(strSubsystem) = 0 Then
         strSubsystem = "Like '*'"
     Else
         strSubsystem = Right(strSubsystem, Len(strSubsystem) - 1)
         strSubsystem = "IN(" & strSubsystem & ")"
     End If
' Build criteria string from status listbox
    For Each varItem In Me.lstStatus.ItemsSelected
         strStatus = strStatus & ",'" & Me.lstStatus.ItemData(varItem) _
         & "'"
     Next varItem
     If Len(strStatus) = 0 Then
         strStatus = "Like '*'"
     Else
         strStatus = Right(strStatus, Len(strStatus) - 1)
         strStatus = "IN(" & strStatus & ")"
     End If

' Build filter string
    strFilter = "[Subsystem] " & strSubsystem & _
                 " AND [Status] " & strStatus

' Apply the filter and switch it on
    With Forms![Filter]
         .Filter = strFilter
         .FilterOn = True
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you drag the report object into your form in design view? If so, I think you created a subform.

Comment: Yes, I dragged the report into the form when it was in design view. Should I be calling it an other way instead of With Reports![List]   ?

Comment: Also, I fixed the "enter parameter" issue but now I have an other issue. The code will filter based on selection and return the values. Problem im having is some fields are blank so it's not returning all records. Is there another way to have it return all records instead of using  If Len(strStatus) = 0 Then
         strStatus = "Like '*'"

Comment: I tried using the following instead but it says "object does not support this property or method"        With Forms!Filter![List]
         .Filter = strFilter
         .FilterOn = True
     End With

Comment: `[List]` is only available as `Reports![List]` when `[List]` was opened directly, not when it is contained within another form or report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is find the name of the subform control which contains the report.  If you have difficulty finding that name when the form is in *Design View*, inspect the form's controls from the Immediate window.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you to the Immediate window.)

Here is an example with my form ...

```vb
for each ctl in Forms!Form10.controls : ? ctl.name, TypeName(ctl) : next
subReport     SubForm
Label0        Label
txtSort          TextBox
Label2        Label
```

So my subform control is named *subReport*.

Once I have that name, I can switch the form back to *Form View* and work with the `Filter` property of the `Report` contained in the subform control ...

```vb
Forms!Form10!subReport.Report.filter = "id=5"
Forms!Form10!subReport.Report.filteron = true
```

The report was immediately filtered to display only the one matching row.

Afterward, I switch off the filter, but the report display did not change until I called `Requery` (on the subform control) ...

```vb
Forms!Form10!subReport.Report.filteron = false
Forms!Form10!subReport.requery
```

If I wanted to do the the filtering from the click event of a command button which was also contained on the parent form, I could shortcut to the control name ...

```vb
Private Sub cmdApplyFilter_Click()
    Me!subReport.Report.Filter = "id=1"
    Me!subReport.Report.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: One last thing, the box that has the filter parameters doesnt have a blank option. So when it filters it's not showing all the records. The blanks are not showing up. I believe it because of the `strStatus = "Like '*'"` since blank is not in the filter options. Is there an other statement I could use when nothing is selected so all records appear? Thank you for your help

Comment: When `Len(strStatus) = 0`, leave that out of the `Filter` string altogether.  In that case, use just this: `strFilter = "[Subsystem] " & strSubsystem`

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a need for you to check whether the report is open if it's embedded as a subform and always appears when the main form is open. Subforms open automatically when the parent form is opened, so unless there is something closing it you shouldn't need to check. When referencing the subform you should be using the `[Forms]!` collection, not the `[Reports]!` collection. Check out [this page](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) for help on referencing subform objects.

I'm not totally clear on the structure of your form, but the reference would probably be:

```
[Forms]![Filter]!SubFormControlNameHere.Report.Filter
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The form name where the List report is located is called Filter. I used "Forms![Filter]" and it wont update the report on the form based on the criteria. How do I specify the subreport? I appreciate the help... i'm not too knowledgeable with VBA