# Run time error -2147417848 (80010108) when disabling FilterOn property of Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on creating filtering options of *myReport* contained in subform container.
I have used solution described in this question:
[Filtering Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919251/filtering-report)

from HansUp. Using described code filter is succesfully created, stored and applied with OnClick event of apllyFilterButton.

Then I create disableFilterButton and in OnClick event I put code suggested in before mentioned thread. While testing, I get this error:

"Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'FilterOn' of object '_Report_myReport' failed"

If I enable/disable filter using Access Ribbon (switch-filter button  on/off) everything works fine with no error. So my mistake might be simple, even in syntax, but I cant find the source.

Code:

```
Private Sub disableFilterButton_Click()
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.FilterOn = False
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.Filter = ""
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Requery
End Sub
```

After crash, using "Debug" option, the first row of code above is highlighted. My research here and around net suggested adding the "blank filter" row, and also registry problem or an existing loop in code, which creates the crash. But since using Ribbon buttons everything works, I think its something simple that I am missing. I am still an beginner.

Code used in myFilterButton to create filter is not fully completed, but should be working:

```
Private Sub applyFilterButton_Click()

Dim ctl As Control
Dim varVyber As Variant
Dim filtrVolba As String
Dim filtrUplny As String

'Criteria creation for filter SQL
 Set ctl = Forms![myForm]![filterOptionOne]
 If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each varVyber In ctl.ItemsSelected
    filtrVolba = filtrVolba & ctl.Column(0, varVyber) & """ OR (sourceQuery.sourceColumn) = """
    Next varVyber

filtrVolba = Left$(filtrVolba, Len(filtrVolba) - Len(" OR (qry_sourceQuery.sourceColumn) = "))
    Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.Filter = "(((sourceQuery.fieldBoundToMyReport)=[Forms]![myForm]![TextBoxBoundToMyReport]) AND ((sourceQuery.filterOptionOneSourceField) = """ & filtrVolba & "))"
 Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.FilterOn = True

Else

MsgBox "Not yet"
End If
End Sub
```

Help will be much appreciated! Thomas

Comment: Strange. Try swapping your `.Filter` and `.FilterOn` lines (clearing the filter first). Can you share the code applying the filter?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Tryed swapping those two lines, gives same error (only swapping Method for 'filter'), again highlighting first row (now the one clearing the filter) while Debuging. I edit the question with used filter code and notify you in comment.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Finished editing

Comment: Don't use a filter  on a report embedded on a form, it seems to be very difficult (Impossible) to make work. 
Instead add the criteria to your reports underlying recordsource and perform a requery. 
I had the same problems and couldn't get past the issue, I used a combo(s) in the form header as the criteria in the end, And reset the combo's to clear the filtering.

Comment: Is this code in the myForm class file, or in a standard module?

Comment: @Minty I actually managed to work around all these issues. I am not removing the filter, instead I am setting the filter SQL to match with criteria for bound-fields, since *myReport* is bound to *myForm* through one field.

But another problem emerged, which is that after filtering and removing the filter I cant set another. One of these operations puts *myForm*,*myReport* or my *filterOptionOne* multi-select listbox to constant refresh, which causes repeating unselecting of ItemsSelected.

I might try to create another question for it... But I am almost finished with making this work :D

Comment: @kismert All the code is in *myForm* class file, not in standard module. I have no code in standard module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomáš,

Since all of the code in your example is in the *myForm* class, let me explain some Access coding basics.

1. The `[Forms]![Form]![Control]` syntax is really intended for Queries, Form & Report events & properties, and Macros. While valid in VBA, there is *no* compile-time verification of this syntax! So, a VBA line like:

   ```
   varValue = [Forms]![Blah]![BlahBlah]  ' doesn't exist
   ```

   will compile OK, but fail at runtime.
2. Controls in a form with a class module become public members of the form class. Take your form *myForm*: you can refer to its controls in code by using:

   ```
   varValue = Form_myForm.filterOptionOne.Value
   ```

   `Form_myForm` is the name of the form class. This line of code *will* throw errors if `filterOptionOne` gets renamed or removed.
3. In any VBA class, `Me` refers to the public interface of that class. "Public interface" simply means all of the public functions, subroutines and properties defined in the class. So, if you were using the line of code above within *myForm*, the best style would look like this:

   ```
   varValue = Me.filterOptionOne.Value
   ```

   `Me` in this context constrains `filterOptionOne` to be actually defined in the class, providing further compile-time checks.

So, in light of these three points, I would refactor your code like so:

```
Private Sub disableFilterButton_Click()
     Me.myReport.Report.FilterOn = False
     Me.myReport.Report.Filter = ""
     Me.myReport.Requery
End Sub
```

Likewise:

```
Private Sub applyFilterButton_Click()

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim varVyber As Variant
    Dim filtrVolba As String
    Dim filtrUplny As String

    'Criteria creation for filter SQL
    Set ctl = Me.filterOptionOne
    If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each varVyber In ctl.ItemsSelected
            filtrVolba = filtrVolba & ctl.Column(0, varVyber) & """ OR (sourceQuery.sourceColumn) = """
        Next varVyber

        filtrVolba = Left$(filtrVolba, Len(filtrVolba) - Len(" OR (qry_sourceQuery.sourceColumn) = "))
        Me.myReport.Report.Filter = "(((sourceQuery.fieldBoundToMyReport)=" & Me.TextBoxBoundToMyReport.Value & ") AND ((sourceQuery.filterOptionOneSourceField) = """ & filtrVolba & "))"
        Me.myReport.Report.FilterOn = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Not yet"
    End If

End Sub
```

This may not solve all your problems, but this should put you on a much sounder footing for understanding how to code Access forms.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Code for applyFilterButton works OK, but disabling filter button happens to be issue. Using code you suggested, Access crashes without any Debug option of error message. Only drops to reset program.
Do you have any idea what could cause this? i am still considering Mintys reaction to choose different approach whatsoever....

Comment: You are doing something that likely can't be adequately diagnosed using the StackOverflow question/answer format. Too many pieces are left out to even guess at what might be wrong. I would offer to look at the whole application, and debug it myself, but I don't have the time to do that right now. So I will end my involvement here by saying "good luck".

Comment: I understand. You already helped me with the recommended coding syntax. I wasnt able to find the source yet and have to put this project on hold. If you would have any suggestion on how to debug whole application it would be most helpfull.

Marking your reaction as answer, since it helped me to understand the topic more, and actually it got me to get rid of the error (eventhough I have gained another :D).

With regards, Tomáš