# Me syntax working instead of writing full control adress. Why?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am kind of new to VBA programming in Access and I have banged upon strange thing. I have system of *`myListbox`* (multi-choice, two of them in testing regime, planning 5 total) to filter *`myReport`* contained in subform container by selected items in those listboxes.

Switching "On" filter works kind of fine (I will address it in different question after doing some research first), but switching filter off turned out to be problem. I was getting error message described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715503/run-time-error-2147417848-80010108-when-disabling-filteron-property-of-report?noredirect=1#comment88439703_50715503).

Managed to find a workaround. **Since I have *`myReport`* bound to control in parent form, I am not switch off filter, instead I am changing it to resemble the bound field criteria, after that switch it off.**

Code:

```
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.Filter = "((sourceQuery.fieldForBoundControl)=Forms![myForm]![boundControl])"
Me.FilterOn = False
```

but if I try this:

```
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.Filter = "((sourceQuery.fieldForBoundControl)=Forms![myForm]![boundControl])"
Forms![myForm]![myReport].Report.FilterOn = False
```

...or any other combination, or simply turning it off, I get error messages and procedure termination. Why?

Is my solution correct for future working of the app or I my setting myself for another Access trap?

Comment: which error messages? where?

Comment: In the case displayed in code its Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108) Function FilterOn failed on the second row of the code. Its described in maximum detail in linked question.

Comment: Is this code in the form's class module, or in a standard module?

Comment: @kismert All code is in class module, this part specifically is in "OnClick" event of "removeFilter" button. I have no code in standard module.

Comment: Tomáš: please consider answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715503/run-time-error-2147417848-80010108-when-disabling-filteron-property-of-report?noredirect=1